# How to get convergence using coxph (R) given that model converges using proc phreg (SAS)

Tags: r, sas, cox-model

I have a data set

```
> head(data)
  id centre        u      time event x c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13 c14
   1      1 0.729891 0.3300478     1 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
   2      1 0.729891 7.0100000     0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
   3      1 0.729891 7.0150000     0 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
   4      1 0.729891 1.3616940     1 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
   5      1 0.729891 7.0250000     0 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
   6      1 0.729891 5.0824055     1 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and I want to fit a proportional hazards model.

**IN R**

I first defined `formula`:

```
> formula
Surv(time, event) ~ x + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + c8 + 
    c9 + c10 + c11 + c12 + c13 + c14
```

and I used the `coxph` function:

```
> library(survival)
> mod <- coxph(formula, data=data)
Erreur dans fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf dans un appel à une fonction externe (argument 6)
De plus : Message d'avis :
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Ran out of iterations and did not converge
```

**IN SAS**

I used `proc phreg`:

```
proc phreg data=data;
    model time*event(0) = x c1-c14 / ties=breslow;
run;
```

Partial output:

```
                      Convergence Status

                     Convergence criterion (GCONV=1E-8) satisfied.
```

#### Question:

- Do you have any suggestion to make it work in R?

I have tried to increase `iter.max` but the problem is still there... If needed, I can provide the data (600 rows).

Comment: What about changing of the starting values? Supply to `init` similar values to the output of SAS and see what happens.

Comment: @mpiktas: Thank you very much !!! It works ! I did not realize that the default initial value is zero for all variables in R. On the other hand, I have still to investigate what are the initial values in SAS. Again, Thank you very much !!!

Comment: glad to be helpful :) Note this is a dirty cheat, since you use other software package to provide starting values, which is not feasible in the long run. But when debugging this is a first thing to try.

Comment: @mpiktas Now, *please*, put this as an answer so that @ocram can accept it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about changing of the starting values? Supply to `init` similar values to the output of SAS and see what happens. This in general is not a good strategy to get the convergence, but it helps to see whether the problem is in algorithm, or just in starting values.

Answer (score 4):

How many events are in the dataset?  The fit from SAS may not be meaningful if there are fewer than a few multiples of the number of covariates (14).

In general with Cox regression I have not had to specify starting values but have occasionally played around with the convergence criteria.